# U-blox 6 GPS module why does it still display points every second when set to 5 minutes?

Tags: arduino, power, gps, update

I'm trying to set up a U-blox 6 GPS module with an Arduino.

In order to save power I have tried to reconfigure it using the U center to search for a fix only once every 5 minutes.  I have read the instructions however probably I don't understand them correctly as the GPS still seems to give a reading for latitude and longitude once every second.  I would like to know why this is and what I am doing wrong if someone could tell me.

The settings I used are:

```
Update Period: 300
Search Period: 150
Grid Offset: 0
Acquisition Timeout: 60
On Time:2
```

While the GPS itself is actually stationary I get results that are changing slightly e.g. as follows from 10:41:24:

```
$GPGLL,4119.01373,S,17445.96088,E,104124.00,A,A*71 10:41:25         
$GPGLL,4119.01371,S,17445.96091,E,104125.00,A,A*7A 10:41:26 
$GPGLL,4119.01373,S,17445.96100,E,104126.00,A,A*72 10:41:27 
$GPGLL,4119.01371,S,17445.96102,E,104127.00,A,A*73 10:41:28 
$GPGLL,4119.01380,S,17445.96110,E,104128.00,A,A*71 10:41:29 
$GPGLL,4119.01380,S,17445.96112,E,104129.00,A,A*72 10:41:30 
$GPGLL,4119.01380,S,17445.96112,E,104130.00,A,A*7A 10:41:31 
$GPGLL,4119.01392,S,17445.96120,E,104131.00,A,A*79 10:41:32
```

Comment: Over that five minutes does the position change at all? It's been a while since I've used a U-Blox but I thought there were different parameters for how often the fix was calculated versus the output rate.

Comment: thanks, yes it does seem to be changing slightly e.g. as follows 10:41:24  $GPGLL,4119.01373,S,17445.96088,E,104124.00,A,A*71
10:41:25  $GPGLL,4119.01371,S,17445.96091,E,104125.00,A,A*7A
10:41:26  $GPGLL,4119.01373,S,17445.96100,E,104126.00,A,A*72
10:41:27  $GPGLL,4119.01371,S,17445.96102,E,104127.00,A,A*73
10:41:28  $GPGLL,4119.01380,S,17445.96110,E,104128.00,A,A*71
10:41:29  $GPGLL,4119.01380,S,17445.96112,E,104129.00,A,A*72
10:41:30  $GPGLL,4119.01380,S,17445.96112,E,104130.00,A,A*7A
10:41:31  $GPGLL,4119.01392,S,17445.96120,E,104131.00,A,A*79
10:41:32

Comment: the GPS itself is actually stationary

Comment: I've just added the info from your comments to the question. I'm heading off soon but if you don't get an answer meanwhile I'll have a better look tomorrow, I think I've got some code somewhere that changes the update period and seem to remember there was some subtle trick.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the problem now...

In the U-blox center Configuration View I changed the settings in the section:

RXM (Receiver Manager) from 
0-Continuous Mode to 1-Power Save mode.

Now it seems to be collecting points only once every 5 minutes as expected :)